# Passing a null value from java for a primary field column of Table is giving wrong answer

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have written a `@NamedNativeQuery` in Java as:

```
SELECT COUNT(e.emp_id) FROM EMP e WHERE e.code = ? AND 
(e.emp_id IS NULL OR e.emp_id != ?) AND e.proj_id = ?")
```

NOTE: `emp_id` is a primary key in `EMP` table.

When I execute this query it returns `0` whenever I pass `null` for primary key data, even though the answer should be something else.

What is wrong in this , `e.emp_id` can have java `null` value, is this causing problem or something else.

Comment: Can you improve your formatting?

Comment: if  `emp_id` can be `null` then it cannot be the primary key.

Comment: Why have you tagged this as relating to JPA and JPA providers?  It is a pure SQL query issue.  Equality checks with null do not work, so your e.emp_id!= null is unknown making the entire condition unknown.  See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements005.htm

Comment: Thanks @JimGarrison and aek8 for the formatting correction.

Comment: @Chris I have removed the unnecessary tags. As per your comment looks like I need to write different query to not pass the null parameter itself to the query and should pass only other two parameter when e.emp_id == null.